# Where can I get the OLD (1940-1970) high school scholarship question papers?

Tags: soft-question

Today matematics are moving away from understanding basics & core methodology. Level of the difficulties are reducing. Questions are becoming more simpler. Hence I would like to see the difficulty level in years Ranging 1940-1970. These Question papers will help improve students to improve in understanding rather than making students to behave like CLERKS by solving repeatadle the similar typ questions not having intelligance in the Questions itself.

Comment: -1.  You haven't given any indication where you're from; what high school papers?  In North America?  Europe?  Japan?  You're also ranting, which is discouraged.

Comment: There were several changes in mathematics education over the time. In the 60's people began to emphasize logical consistency, abstract structures etc. this was called New Math (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Math) in the US. Similar attempts was made all over the world for example in Germany. I think in the last 20 years mathematics education emphasizes more and more modelling, applying mathematics to every-day life, tries to give questions with has solutions on multiple levels etc. abstract concepts, rigorous definitions etc. however are not longer so important...

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [this](http://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx) (old IMO problems).

Comment: This might be of interest also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384/sources-of-problems-for-teaching-tutoring-young-mathematicians

Comment: Old IMO problems are _easier_ than new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some problems from the Stanford scholarship examination. I found them on the easier side, but that may be because they are quite old. I feel competitive mathematics has become significantly harder in the past, say, 20 years, but that is just a personal opinion.

[http://www.amazon.com/Stanford-Mathematics-Problem-Book-Solutions/dp/0486469247](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486469247)